# Find and replace word in text file

Tags: php

I want to detect if a word in a text file exists, and then remove it.. so, this is my code:

```
<?php
$search = $id;
$lines = file("./user/".$_GET['own'].".txt");
// Store true when the text is found
$found = false;
foreach($lines as $line)
{
if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
{
$found = true;
// open to read and modify
$file = "./user/".$_GET['own'].".txt";
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
$data = fread($fh, filesize($file));
$new_data = str_replace($id."\n", "", $data);
fclose($fh);
// Open to write
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
fwrite($fh, $new_data);
fclose($fh);
$status = "has been successfully deleted.";
}
}
// If the text was not found, show a message
if(!$found)
{
 $status = "is not exist in your list.";
}
?>
```

I got this work hours before.. I did some changes to my script and somehow, it didnt work anymore.. can anyone see through the code and tell me what is wrong??

or can anybody give simpler way to do what I want?? my code is messed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to detect if a word in a text file exists, and then remove it..

```
<?php
 $search = $id;
 $filename="./user/".$_GET['own'].".txt";
 $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
 $contents = str_replace($id."\n", "", $contents);
 file_put_contents($filename,$contents);
?>
```

That is all that there is to it.

**Edit:**

To make this equivalent to your solution, one can use

```
<?php
 $search = $id;
 $filename="./user/".$_GET['own'].".txt";
 $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
 $contents = str_replace($id."\n", "", $contents,$count);
 if($count>0)
 {
  file_put_contents($filename,$contents);
  echo "found and removed";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "not found";
 }
?>
```

Comment: thats all???? -_- how shame when my code are triple longer than yours.. btw, I will test it in a minute

Comment: Yep that's all, the only thing missing here is your conditional `echo`

Comment: once again your code better than me.. thanks bro.. you're the best.. I coded the messed code for 1/2 hour and you make cleaner code within minutes.. :)