# How to replace a word in a file with a hyperlink in PHP?

Tags: php

I need a help with replacing a word from a text file to a link using php

This is my code:

```
<?php
$search = 'google';
$lines = file('f.txt');
foreach($lines as $line)
{
   if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
   echo $search."\n";
   echo preg_replace('/google/', '<a href="http://www.google.com/'></a>',$lines);

   }
}
?>
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901521/replace-string-in-text-file-using-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039823/find-and-replace-word-in-text-file

Comment: You have a typing mistake here '<a href="http://www.google.com/'></a>' after .com/ you have single quote, should be double.

Comment: Your link still needs to have the original text between the `<a>...`</a>` tags, otherwise there won't be anything to click.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little example coded up for you that will illustrate the general idea.

```
<a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?replace=yes">Replace a word</a>
```

The `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variable points to the current file.

```
if (isset($_GET['replace']) && $_GET['replace'] == 'yes') {

    // Define filename
    $filename = 'somefile.txt';

    // Get file contents
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);

    // Replace the word
    $contents = str_replace('someword', 'replacewith', $contents);

    // Write back to file
    file_put_contents($filename, $contents);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really helpful.

Comment: @M.Fooz Glad to be of help. You can thank me by accepting my answer as the best answer at the left side of my answer.